# How do I install and use the custom CSSLint rules I have written for the CLI?

Tags: css, npm, installation, lint, csslint

I am using CSSLint via the CLI. I have spent quite a bit of time following the steps found [here](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Developer-Guide) and [here](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Working-with-Rules) to  write custom css linting rules. They are tested and they work correctly, however now that I have created the rules I am not sure how to actually add them to the linter (or installed via npm) so that can be used via the CLI to lint my projects. I have scoured the documentation in the github wiki and cannot seem to find an answer.

Keep in mind these rules are project specific and they are not meant to be submitted to the csslint github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I used 'grunt release' and then published it as an npm module, and then installed it. The cause for the issue was that I needed to uninstall the original version of cssLint as it was overriding the new one.